# How to retrieve values from an input element in html

Tags: jquery, json, forms, input, document

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#center").click(function{ });
}
```

I know that you can get documentbyID with javascript. How do I get the value of a form input with jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery get form field value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654449/jquery-get-form-field-value)

Answer (score 0):

To get value of a form input , use

```
$("#idOfInput").val();
$(".classOfInput").val();
$("[name='yourInputName']").val();
```

HTML

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="yourInputName" class="classOfInput" id="idOfInput"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The function for getting the value in jquery is `val()`

Comment: Why downvotes ? I was falling asleep(its 12.15 AM here). It was just a typo.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to alert the value and you are using jquery:

```
function foo(){
    alert($("#myInput").val());
}
```

And your html:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="myInput" id="myInput"/>
</form>
<button onclick="foo()">Click</button>
```

Here is a fiddle as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6tge2fx4/