# How to get the text content inside a Text Area with Jquery using its class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an automatically generated textarea with a class name, say "x". How do I get the text inside the text area given that there will be only one element with the class name "x" in that page.

I have tried the following and can't make it to work.

```
<textarea class="note-codable" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" style="height: 390px;">
 some content 
</textarea>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert($('.note-codable').val());
  alert($('.note-codable').first.val());
  alert($('.note-codable').text());
})
```

also how do i update the same text area?
any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: use  `$('.x').val();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery get form field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654449/jquery-get-form-field-value)

Answer (score 2):

You Can Use:

$(selector).text() i.e

```
$('.x').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.val()`. Its working fine

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.note-codable'))
  alert($('.note-codable').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="note-codable" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" style="height: 390px;">
 some content 
</textarea>
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question now. It still doesn't work for me. Actually I'm trying to update content to a rich text editor. there is this role="textbox" after the class name. is this what causing failure?

Comment: Yes. I know, I think it has something to do with the rich text editor i'm trying to play with.

Comment: I'm Using summernote RTE with Django.

Comment: @ArunLaxman buddy i just saw https://summernote.org/. Go and **inspect element** the the RTE. You will see that `<textarea>` have no `innerHTML` or text. A `<div>` below it contains the the whole text. Try using `$('.note-editable').text();`

Comment: I'm really grateful to you for going to such extreme lengths. but there's a textarea for codeview. if you inspect the codeview of Summernote, you get a textarea with note-codable class name.

Answer (score 1):

check below code for this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert($('.x:first').html());
})
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That's actually misleading. Although a textarea does not have a value _attribute_, it still exposes a value _property_ to be accessed with JavaScript

Comment: Thanks for correcting me and I have updated my comment which was misleading @Psi